# wget magento-2.0.5 to download magento CE- not found

Tags: magento

I was trying to download magento2.0.5 on linux using command
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/2.0.4/magento-2.0.4.tar.gz

error returned-
Connecting to magento.com (magento.com)|66.211.190.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

Is the download url changed? or are there some new permission constraints I need to pass through?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try here

https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

If you are looking for download link then here

https://github.com/magento/magento2/archive/2.3.0.tar.gz

I tried and this link works.